# How to add an image to a frame in AWT?

Tags: java, awt

I tried this, but it does not work work.

```java
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Panel;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

public class Gfx
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Frame f = new Frame ("Gfx");
    f.addWindowListener (new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
          f.dispose (); }});
    Panel p = new Panel ();
    f.add(p);
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1000, 1000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    p.add(image);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible (true);
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
Gfx.java:21: error: no suitable method found for add(BufferedImage)
    p.add(image);
     ^
    method Component.add(PopupMenu) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; BufferedImage cannot be converted to PopupMenu)
    method Container.add(Component) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; BufferedImage cannot be converted to Component)
```

The `BufferedImage` is no `Component`. How to convert it into a `Component`?

Comment: You need to add your image to a container like a `Panel`.

Comment: @QBrute Panel does not help. Same error.

Comment: Why AWT? Better to use Swing -- put the image into an ImageIcon, put that into a JLabel and then display the JLabel in a JFrame. AWT has been out of date for over 20+ years and is well past its EOL.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Some teacher or tutorial created his lesson plan 20 years ago and is not going to change it for the latest fads. /s  I remember waiting 20 years between COBOL revisions.  In my opinion, a new Java release every six months is way too often.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: I cannot disagree with you regarding Java releases, and being forced to stay au courant with every small change, but gosh, AWT was superseded by Swing **26** years ago. That's almost a full generation ago, *human* generation, not software cycle generation. And, as I'm sure you know, Swing has been superseded since then by JavaFX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw using AWT, you use a `Canvas`.  In Java Swing, you create a drawing `JPanel`.

I modified your code to create the following GUI:

[image: GUI]

I reduced the image size so the GUI fits in the answer better.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Gfx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame f = new Frame("Gfx");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                f.dispose();
            }
        });

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(200, 200,
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
            }
        };

        f.add(canvas);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Full example with some drawing:

```java
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Gfx
{
  static final int width = 800;
  static final int height = 600;

  static Frame frame (String title)
  {
    Frame frame = new Frame (title);
    frame.addWindowListener (new WindowAdapter ()
      {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing (WindowEvent ev) { frame.dispose (); }
      });
    return frame;
  }

  static BufferedImage image ()
  {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage (width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();
    graphics.setColor (Color.RED);
    graphics.fillPolygon (new int[] {width, 0, 0}, new int[] {height/2, 0, height}, 3);
    graphics.dispose ();
    return image;
  }

  static Canvas canvas (Image image)
  {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas ()
      {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize () {
          return new Dimension (width, height); }
        @Override
        public void paint (Graphics graphics)
        {
          super.paint (graphics);
          graphics.drawImage (image, 0, 0, this); // this?
        }
      };
    return canvas;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Frame frame = frame ("Gfx");
    Image image = image ();
    Canvas canvas = canvas (image);
    frame.add (canvas);
    frame.pack ();
    frame.setVisible (true);
  }
}
```